# zenbook pro 15 ux580ge screenpad issue ubuntu 20.4 focal fossa

Tags: asus, nvidia-geforce

I have zenbook pro 15 ux580ge  where i installed ubuntu 20.4 focal fossa, As dual boot
Drivers installed-
Nvidia driver -440
Intel GPU is also enabled

Everything is working fine except the screenpad !!
How can i use it as secondary display?
Xrandr shows it disconnected
It lights up at the Boot..
Need solution.. please do reply

Comment: I have the same setup with ux581, ubuntu budgie works great, also focal fossa. Maybe try that